# How can I make Skype love my X230's microphone?

Tags: windows-7, skype, thinkpad, microphone

Skype's showing my Thinkpad X230 no love.  It's only able to transfer about 50% of the audio.  It appears to work for .5 second, dropout for .5 second, repeat continually...  Tests fine, works fine in other apps, seems Skype specific.  OS and drivers are all current.  I've tried disabling the auto-gain and manually setting it, no joy.  Ideas?

Comment: What's your Internet connection like?

Comment: Big and lightly used.  Other machines have no problem.

Comment: If the mic works with other programs, it is unlikely that it is a Thinkpad issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go to Control Panel
click on REaltek HD Audio Manager
Click on Microphone
Diable Microphone Effect.

It will work. (Skype or Gtalk)

Comment: Excellent!  Works perfect now!  Apparently the built-in echo cancelation (that I never noticed) interfered with Skype's echo cancelation!

Comment: Update, the latest version of the drivers have several options that may need to be twiddled based on software in use.  On my system Skype wants a certain set of them, and Bria a totally different set.